# cost-benefit of high-performance machines with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, distributed-computing

I have just read through some excellent documentation on Hadoop [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module1.html). It appears that one of the main advantages of Hadoop over other approaches to computationally expensive data processing (e.g. [heterogenous computing](http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/what-is-heterogeneous-computing/)) is its [scalability](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module1.html#scalability). It leverages large numbers modest-cost hardware instead of any single powerful but expensive machine.

Suppose we have the option of using high-performance but expensive machines for Hadoop computing. Can and does Hadoop effectively utilize these expensive resources; does it automatically leverage additional [EC2 compute units](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it) or do you have to do the parallel programming yourself? How much improvement in performance machines? Is there a method to quantify performance gains for the price of more [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#on-demand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hadoop framework automatically leverages multiple cores when they are available. You don't have to do the parallel programming yourself, and this is actually one of the selling points of Hadoop: you just need to write your job once without worrying about thread synchronization logic, and then depending on the configuration of your cluster it will try to use all cores as much as possible.

For example, suppose you have a job running on a multi-terabyte dataset which after computing the splits requires 100 tasks to run. Now if you want to run your job on 10 m1.small nodes (which have only 1 core), your cluster will have a capcity of 10 tasks at a time (1 task per node). But if you want to run it on for example 10 m1.large nodes (2 x 2 cores), you will have a capacity of 40 tasks at a time, so your job will be roughly 4 times faster than if you were using the same number of m1.small because it will take advantage of the additional cores.

Additionally, I've heard of people using CUDA on Hadoop (some information [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CUDA%20On%20Hadoop)) and Amazon has some cluster GPU instances, so in this case you could probably take advantage of the GPU as well.

The bottom line is, when using Hadoop you should be reasoning in terms of number of cores, not in number of machines. Obviously you want to find a good tradeoff, I've seen in the past a cluster where each node had a lot of cores but the disk I/O wasn't great, so this caused a lot of contention in the cluster and we had to reduce the max number of tasks per node (which you can control in the Hadoop configs via the parameters `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`).

I've personally found the m1.xlarge instances to work very well in some Hadoop clusters, while the high-CPU ones caused too much disk contention for me.